# Can I use the top box screws for a ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I've installed ceiling fans before but this is the first time I've seen screws like this coming from the top of the box. Can I use these screw for the mounting bracket or will I need to remove the box to remove the screws and then attach the mounting bracket to holes on the bottom of the box?

Are these a common type of mounting screw?

[image: Screws from top of electrical box]

[image: another one]

Comment: I believe that those bolts (or "studs") are expressly for the purpose of hanging a fan or a heavy light fixture. Obviously you myst have the correct nuts on these bolts. Did nuts come with it? If not, you will have to get the correct nuts and perhaps also washers to properly secure the fan lunting bracket. In this context a "stud" is a type of bolt for which one end is attached to massice member and the other end projects from the member and is threaded to receive a nut and often a washer.

Comment: Yep I still have the nuts. I wasn't sure just due to never coming across it like that before. I've always screwed the mounting bracket into the holes on the side. Thank you!

Comment: The holes in the tabs on the corners are designed to hold a cover or a very light fixture. They do not have enought threads to be rated to hold a heavy weight and the tabs themselves are not rated for heavy weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the labels in that box. I'm pretty sure that's rated for a ceiling fan and the bracket mounts to the studs. Hopefully you saved the nuts.

Comment: The box is secured to a framing member by either screws or other fasteners and these studs are firmly attached to the box. The fan is attached to the studs by washers and nuts. Sometiomes the nut has a "washer" incorportated into the nut and sometimes the washer is separate.

Comment: Yep I still have the nuts. I wasn't sure just due to never coming across it like that before. I've always screwed the mounting bracket into the holes on the side. The box is rated for 35 pounds(ceiling fan is 20 pounds) so it should be okay.Thank you!